# Android I want to stream images from online database

Tags: android, mysql, database, image, parsing

I am new to Android so I want to create a background wallpaper app. I made the offline version already which displays images from an array using ImageAdapter.
But I want make it online so that the images will be downloaded and displayed from an online database. What would be the simple and best way to do it? An example would be preferred.

Comment: Picasso and Glide, two simple libraries are available and numerous examples too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Picasso library. Image loading using Picasso is very easy, you can do it like this way

> Picasso.with(context).load("https://i.stack.imgur.com/jEIKP.jpg").into(imageView);

and in their [website](http://square.github.io/picasso/) you can get every details.

and another Library is Glide. You can use Glide too for loading image..

Answer (score 1):

Just use Picasso, it's pretty simple and lightweight library with good documentation. You also can save images from network with some hacks.
http://square.github.io/picasso/